# How to run java11 and jfx11 application on jre1.8

Tags: java, maven, javafx, deployment, javafx-11

I am a computer student and I had during my internship in a company, develop a small java software using JavaFX, maven, and apache.poi.

Info: The application works on Intellij and builds perfectly, my problem concerns the `*.jar` that I generate once the project is finished.

I first used JDK 14 and JFX14, however at the time of the execution (java –jar xx.jar) I had an error saying that I was compiling the program in JAVA 58 (JAVA 14) and that I was using JRE 52 (JAVA 8).

So I modified the project to compile with JDK 11 and JFX 11, and I now have the same error telling me that I am compiling the program in JAVA 55 (JAVA 11) and that I was using JRE 52 (JAVA 8).

The error comes from the fact that my PC uses jre1.8.0_251 by default.

So I tried to launch the program in this way "path_to_jdk11 \ bin \ java.exe" -jar xxx.jar and it works.

So that's my problem:

The majority of users use the version of JAVA offered on the Oracle site, i.e. jre1.8.0_251 which is the latest version available. Outside my program requires Java 11, which is not deploying on corporate PCs, I imagine.
I tried to port my project to java 8 but I have errors with Maven and the module.info.java.

Do you have a tip for deploying the `*.jar` or deploying it in `.exe` so that it can run with a user who has jre1.8.0_251?

Respectfully

Comment: The only possibilities you have are to either completly port the project to java 8 or you build it with java 11 and include a jre that runs the program. With Java 11 came jlink, which is exactly for there purposes. it builds a custom jre with the components your program needs

Comment: I try to use Jlink, but I use apache.poi in my project, so when i run javafx:jlink i have this error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: poi from xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to build a fat jar. It won't work with modern Java. Instead build a real installer. This can be done easily with JDK 14+. Just follow this tutorial https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX which covers everything you need. This uses jpackage from JDK 14 and some other tools from it and also works with non-modularized projects. When you install JDK 14 just make sure you set JAVA_HOME and your PATH correctly so that all the tools find the correct version of Java for building.